# Automate set up and driver installs on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, batch, setup

I have to set up a large amount of PCs all with a fresh install of Windows 7 or XP, all with the same settings using the options in the control panel, and all with similar hardware drivers. The only variable is the make/model of the hardware, e.g different Motherboard models.

I would like to automate the process, so it changes power, display, system, firewall etc settings without me having to go into the control panel and change them manually. The second, slightly more difficult task is installing the motherboard USB drivers, graphics card drivers, network adapters etc. The difficulty is that the make/model of the hardware varies from PC to PC.

Can I do this with a batch file with conditional statements? If I can, what are the basic commands that I will need to use? Or is there a better way to do this?

I have experience with a few Procedural programming languages, and basic command line usage on windows and Linux, and so I do not mind learning a new language to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an image of C drive(or whichever drive you're installing in) after installing windows and drivers on 1 particular machine. Then record and copy that image into the other machines.

If they're on similar hardware, then windows should refresh the hardware IDs and refresh the drivers from its driver-store. In case of different drivers, just copy all the drivers into the image, and let windows scan the location for installing drivers. Once done you could delete the extra files.

If you have yet another computer for doing this on, you could just clone disk partitions by using the first machine's HDD as the master source, and then place the copied disks into the machines as you go along.